# Compatibility issue while using Apache POI in Android

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I am getting following issue while using Apache POI

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. 
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I have added the following repository in my gradle dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.14-beta1'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14-beta1'
}
```

I have also tested from poi version `3.9`. But every time I got the same issue.

If I commented

```
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14-beta1'
```

App runs without any exception.

Answer (score 2):

Your app has over 65k Methods when adding the library. You need to enable multi-dex then, for this modify your gradle build file like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

And in your Manifest add the MultiDexApplication class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

see http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Added +1, I will check it and then will accept it as a correct answer if it works.